# Adding tooltip to icon button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am attempting to add an md tooltip to an md-icon button as follows:

```
<div
    layout = 'row'
    layout-align = 'center center'>
  <button
      md-icon-button
      color = 'primary'
      (click) = 'resetInputForm()'>
    <md-icon class = 'md-24'>cached</md-icon>
    md-tooltip='Reset' tooltip-position='above'
  </button>
</div>
```

However, the literal text of the icon tooltip is displayed to the page instead of the message as shown in the image below:

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the tooltip as atributte in the button tag:

```
 <button
  md-icon-button
  color = 'primary'
  (click) = 'resetInputForm()'
  md-tooltip='Reset'
  tooltip-position='above'>
        <md-icon class = 'md-24'>cached</md-icon>
 </button>
```

Comment: Following your instructions result in an error where an Overlay provider is missing. I cannot seem to find it in angular. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to add in your app.module.ts: import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from "@angular2-material/core"; and in providers: OVERLAY_PROVIDERS

Comment: Using the property tooltip-positon='right' always throws an error. Any idea what is happening here. Thanks

Comment: There is no position "right", only "above"|"below"|"before"|"after". You can read in the documentation: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/README.md